# How to load R reference classes stored in the inst folder?

Tags: r, reference-class

I have some code that I want to run when a user loads my package. That code includes creating a reference class (Parent) and `source`ing a file stored under `inst`. Here is a toy version:

```
Parent <- setRefClass("Parent",
    methods = list(
        initialize = function() { }
    )
)

.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
    temp <- new.env()
    file <- system.file("example.R", package = "examplerefclass")
    sys.source(file, envir = temp)
    objects <- ls(temp)
    print(objects)
}
```

`example.R` file defines a reference class.

```
library(methods)
Child <- setRefClass("Child", contains = "Parent")
```

I had to call `library(methods)` because the `methods` package is not defined when `.onLoad` runs. So, this works, but I get an error when I run `R CMD check` and I don't know how to avoid it.

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'examplerefclass', details:
  call: initialize(value, ...)
  error: attempt to apply non-function
```

The error refers to the `initialize` function defined in `Parent`. Somehow, the `Child` class is not seeing it during the `R CMD check` process, but it works in interactive mode.

I know what I'm doing is unconventional but I don't see any other way to meet my design requirements. For a number of reasons `example.R` must be stored in `inst`, and I need to check what `objects` are defined in `example.R` without sourcing it in the current environment (if the right objects are defined, I then go on to source `example.R` but that is another story).

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

I've set up the toy example in a git repo for easy testing: https://github.com/nachocab/examplerefclass

Comment: Does it work if `example.R` is put in the `R` folder?  Having R code outside of that location is liable to break things.

Comment: Also, consider having an explicit dependency on the `methods` package in your `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. R loads `methods` by default. The only reason why I make the explicit call is because it is loaded *after* `.onLoad`. Also, if I put `example.R` in the `R` folder the example no longer makes sense.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do with `example.R`.  If it demonstrates a function, then it belongs in that function's `Rd` file in the `man` directory.  If it is a longer example then it should be in a demo (in the `demo` dir) or a vignette (in the `vignettes` dir).  In any case, you shouldn't be calling it from `.onLoad`.

Comment: The point of the package I'm building is to allow users to share visualization functions (bit.ly/rclickme) without having them create individual R packages. `example.R` would provide R helper functions to use with a specific visualization. I know this goes beyond conventional R usage, that's why I wanted to conform as much as possible to R CMD check.